# changing port on sendmail and checking it to make sure it works

Tags: sendmail, fedora

I am using smart_host and it(mail.myotherdomain.com) is listening on PORT 26

I have put these two lines in my **/etc/mail/sendmail.mc**

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`mail.myotherdomain.com')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 26')dnl
```

I then do

```
make -C /etc/mail
service sendmail restart
```

Is there a way to verify that it is actually using port 26?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to telnet to the box, using port 26.

`telnet localhost 26`

Then, issue some SMTP commands to test.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure something is listening on port 26:

```
$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep 26
```

Then, if there is, from another host on your network, try and connect via telnet:

```
$ telnet <IP_address> 26
```

If sendmail answers, you're good.

**BUT**

Why do you want to do this? The email transport system is fairly rigid with regards to what ports SMTP happens on, and if you want a prayer of being able to interact with other mail systems, you have no choice but to have your MTA listening on port 25.

Comment: I thought the RELAY_MAILER_ARGS is setting it up to use a different port of the smarthost (mail.myotherdomain.com).
what i am try to accomplish is send mail from this server via my mail server that has a port 26 that allows relaying from my Class C. So i am trying to test that the smarthost is sending out the rely to port 26. I hope that clarifies things alittle better

Comment: Well if it's your own infrastructure, then use whatever ports you want. You do know, however, that classful addressing died **20 years** ago, right?

Comment: so any help or just snarkyness??

Comment: Not trying to be snarky, just honest. No one uses classful addressing any more. My answer contains what you need to know to test whether or not sendmail is running on port 26, correct?

Comment: thanks for the help. I know its listening on 26. I am using smarthost to rely to another server that is listening on 26. I am verify that the relay is leaving on 26